# Adding active states to hyperlinks when clicked

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-hover

I am having some trouble in trying to add an active state to my links. This the code I am playing with:

```
$(function () {

    $('a').click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('PnavCurrent');
        //$("div a").removeClass("PnavCurrent");
        //$("div a[href="+newHash+"]").addClass("PnavCurrent");

        $(this).removeClass('PnavCurrent');
        $(this).css('color', '#51ad9d');
        $(this).css('z-index', '2');
        $(this).css('border-color', '#00a8ff');

        $('a').hover($(this).css('z-index', '10'));
    });
});
```

For some reason it won't apply the css active state class ('PnavCurrent') for the links but it does work correctly when I specify it in the script code with `{$(this).css...}`. Now what I would like is at add an hover state z-index for the links in the script code, something like this:

```
 $('a').hover($(this).css ('z-index', '10'));
```

I've tried to use that little block of code above in trying to achieve this but it doesn't work. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone could help with this and possibly a better solution overall.

Comment: You're adding then removing the classs `PnavCurrent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
.PnavCurrent {
    color: #51ad9d;
    z-index: 2;
    border-color: #00a8ff;
}

.PnavCurrent:hover { z-index: 10; }
```

Javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function(e) {
        // you usually want to prevent default for handling link clicks,
        // otherwise the browser follows the href (if that's intended skip this)
        e.preventDefault();

        $('a').not(this).removeClass('PnavCurrent');
        $(this).addClass('PnavCurrent');
    });
});
```

---

Note on [jQuery `.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/):
You dont need this here at all, but the usage would be this (this is an *alternative* to the css `:hover` rule, not used together)

```
$("a").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).css('z-index',2));
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).css('z-index', 10);
    }
);
```

Comment: Sorry for the long response time. I think something in my css is conflicting with this script, because when I test on a new file (html and css) from scratch it works, though there are some issues like it not remembering my link's active state on page reload etc. But overall it works. Thanks a lot nbrooks. You have been a really big help and I appreciate it.