# Apply the class "active" to nav links when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website is a parallax one page scrolling website, so all my nav links are directed to ids nested within that page...

For example:

```
<ul class="clearfix">
    <li><a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

So How would I tell my html that when someone clicks on one of these links and directs them to the corresponding ID on the page, to take on the class active? And the link that was active to turn back to the regular styling?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding active states to hyperlinks when clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11571098/adding-active-states-to-hyperlinks-when-clicked)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your link elements are contained in an element with class `nav`, and you're using jQuery, you could do the following:

```
$('.nav a').on('click', function(event) {
    $('.nav a.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/70Lfa7d2/3)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery

```
$('ul a').on('click', function(event) {
    $('a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Replace `ul a` with something more specific like `.nav a`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use JavaScript to add that functionality into your application. Everytime a link is clicked, add the 'active' class to the triggering element, and remove it from all others. This is straightforward if you can use jQuery ([***jsFiddle with jQuery***](http://jsfiddle.net/ezjabab5/1/)), and only a little more tedious otherwise.

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.clearfix > li > a").click(function() {
        $("a.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

If you're only using native JS, you can try something along the lines of the below ([***jsFiddle using vanilla JS***](http://jsfiddle.net/ezjabab5/)):

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a"); // more specific selector if other links
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var link = links[i];
    link.onclick = function () {
        var prev = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
        if (prev && prev[0]) {
            prev[0].className = ""; // if using other classes, filter better
        }
        this.className += " active";
    };
}
```

This second solution needs to be adapted to fit your particular application/DOM structure, since it's not quite as flexible as the first.

Comment: Thank you! Your first solution worked. Would you know any way to also apply the active when the user scrolls down to the specific id?